# Not able to install Visual studio code on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I am getting this error while installing Visual studio code on ubuntu.

I tried these commands,first three worked but I am getting an error after the fourth one.

1. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make
2. sudo apt-get update
3. sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make
4. umake web visual-studio-code

   usage: umake web [-h] {firefox-dev,phantomjs} ...
   umake web: error: argument framework: invalid choice: 'visual-studio-code' (choose from 'firefox-dev', 'phantomjs')

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the last command, according to [ubuntu-make](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make) and https://askubuntu.com/a/616363/861358 it should be like this:

```
umake ide visual-studio-code
```

Please note that there are also other ways to install Visual Studio Code discribed in the [official Documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux):

> ## Installation
>
> ### Debian and Ubuntu based distributions
>
> The easiest way to install Visual Studio Code for Debian/Ubuntu based
> distributions is to download and install the [.deb package (64-bit)](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=760868),
> either through the graphical software center if it's available, or
> through the command line with:
>
> ```
> sudo apt install ./<file>.deb
>
> # If you're on an older Linux distribution, you will need to run this instead:
> # sudo dpkg -i <file>.deb
> # sudo apt-get install -f
> ```
>
> Install dependencies Installing the .deb package will automatically install the apt repository and signing key
> to enable auto-updating using the system's package manager. Note that
> 32-bit and .tar.gz binaries are also available on the [download page](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download).
>
> The repository and key can also be installed manually with the
> following script:
>
> ```
> curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > microsoft.gpg
> sudo install -o root -g root -m 644 microsoft.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/
> sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list'
> ```
>
> Then update the package cache and install the package using:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
> sudo apt-get update
> apt-get install code # or code-insiders
> ```

Comment: I would appreciate if you mark my answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not able to compile Visual Studio Code, yourself, you can follow these steps to install a compiled binary directly.

1. First update packages (by code below)

   ```
   $sudo apt update

   $sudo apt install software-properties-common apt-transport-https wget
   ```
2. Now import Microsoft's GPG Key (by code below)

   ```
   $wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc -O- |
   sudo apt-key add -
   ```
3. Now enable Visual Code repository (by code below)

   ```
   $sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main"
   ```
4. Now just install Visual Studio Code  (by code below)

   ```
   $sudo apt update

   $sudo apt install code
   ```